# Django REST Swagger - Gera 2 metodos GET

Tags: python, django, rest, swagger

Estou implementando uma API REST com Django REST Swagger 2.2.0.

Para um determinado endpoint defini que esteja disponível os seguintes métodos:

```
http_method_names = ['post', 'put', 'get']
```

Porém, no swagger, aparece 2 versões para o método GET:

```
1 - http://dominio/nome_metodo
2 - http://dominio/nome_metodo/{id}
```

Como faço para que o Swagger oculte o método 2?

Answer (score 0):

Se a classe que está utilizando herdar de ModelViewSet automaticamente será gerado estas urls.
Uma solução é realiza herança múltilpla com outras [cdrf](http://www.cdrf.co/)

```
from rest_framework.mixins import ListModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, CreateModelMixin
from rest_framework.views import  GenericViewSet
Class MinhaViewSet(ListModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
   ...
```